# Unable to insert and check for similar data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to insert an account into the database. I shall briefly explain what my codes does before adding my syntax below. Generally, I'm checking if the particular textbox is empty. if it's not, it will attempt to insert data into the database. However, if the database contain a data similar to what is being type in the textbox they will prompt different error respectively. Unfortunately, for mine, i'm not even able to insert any data and there's also no error to show that the data in the textbox and database is the same

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tbpid.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Please generate a police ID for this account";
        }
        else if (tbfullname.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Please type the full name of the police officer";
        }
        else if (tbnric.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Please enter the NRIC of the police officer";
        }
        else if (ddllocation.SelectedValue.Equals("Select Location"))
        {
            lbmsg.Text = "Please select the location of the policepost he will be posted to";
        }
        else { 

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand("Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid = @policeid", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;

select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policeid", tbpid.Text);

        dr = select.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            if (tbpid.Equals(dr["policeid"].ToString()))
            {

                lbmsg.Text = "Police ID already exists. Please generate another new Police ID";

            }
            else if (tbnric.Equals(dr["nric"].ToString()))
            {
                lbmsg.Text = "NRIC already exists. Please ensure the NRIC is correct";
            }

        }

        else
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PoliceAccount(policeid, password, nric, fullname, postedto)  values('" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbpid.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbnric.Text.Trim() + "','" + tbfullname.Text.Trim() + "', '" + ddllocation.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            Response.Redirect("AdminAddAccount");

        }

        }

    }
```

***Please refer to this [thread for the correct answer][1]***

Comment: Please use prepared statements when constructing sql statements. This approach is a SQL injection disaster waiting to happen

Comment: Your select statement is very inefficient as well. You should make the select statement be `select * from policeAccount where policeid = <PoliceID> or nric = <nric>`

The way you have it now, you are not letting SQL do what SQL is good at doing

Comment: To be honest, The way i type the syntax of my SQL statement are what my school taught me. I have never really heard of such thing called prepared statement. Moreover, i'm doing a project that will be used by me only.

Answer (score 1):

It never gets into the else, to insert data, because your select statement isn't filtered. This statement:

```
Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount
```

will return all rows from that table. However, what you really want is:

```
Select policeid, nric from PoliceAccount where policeid = @policeid
```

and then, before executing the reader, add this line of code:

```
select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@policeid", tbpid.Text);
```

Finally, use that same parameterized syntax on the insert statement, it's safe from SQL Injection.

Comment: somehow, i'm able to insert the data into the database. However, my error checking for similiar data in the textbox and database isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

What The Solution has said is right. Also add `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` in your code before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Also I think that you should add `.aspx` here `Response.Redirect("AdminAddAccount.aspx");`